# How can I do a matplotlib scatter plot with a categorical x-axis, that allows me to specify the marker and color based on a third variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker, scatter

Here is my dataframe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJQWg.png

I need a matplotlib scatter plot that has the movie title as the label on the x-axis, in the order given by the 'Order' column.  I also want the color of the markers to be determined by the genre of the movie. How can I do this with Matplotlib?

Note that I would ideally like to use the object-oriented approach to matplotlib - i.e. using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the text directly into your question. You can either format it as a code block or a table.

Comment: @ Chris - apologies this was my first post. Noted for future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only specify your x-values and not your y-values, it is difficult to know your exact goal. But you can use the following code to create a scatter plot with categorical data. I chose to plot the 'Order' column as y-values, but you can also modify the code to plot something else or reorder you data as you like. So here you go:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Order': np.arange(4), 'Movie Title': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'Genre': ['genre2', 'genre1', 'genre1','genre2']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['Movie Title'], df['Order'],
           c=['blue' if g=='genre1' else 'red' for g in df['Genre']])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what I was after. Apologies, I should have specified that I wanted the y-axis to be the 'Rating'.  Is there a way to also choose the marker style based on the value in the 'Lead Gender' column?

Comment: plt.scatter() does not support marker lists, but here is a solution https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11155

Comment: Thanks re Scatter.  Back to the original question, how can I add a legend that matches the colors I've chosen. i.e. in your example genre1 = blue and genre 2 = red?